# I want to add a password to access to the frontend ONLY for one store of my multi-stores

Tags: multistore, frontend, password

I have a multi-stores who contains 2 different store.
One store is OK and is in production.
The second store is ine developpement, and I would like to add a password to avoid people to see it during the developpement.

Please could you explain to me how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Which server do you use? Is it apache or nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the fastest solution is to add this in your .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Locked"
Require valid-user

SetEnvIf Host example.com secure_content

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=secure_content

Satisfy Any
```

You have to change the path to .htpasswd file (/var/www/html/.htpasswd) and your domain name of the second store (example.com). Also you have to add .htpasswd file with username and password. You can search in google for this. There are a lot of explanation and generators (for example - http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/).